# How to show that a point with positive coordinates in $\ell^p$ is not a support point of the positive wedge?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

> **Definition of a support point:**
>
> Let $X$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}, P\subseteq X$ is a set, a point $\xi\in P$ is said to be a support point of $P$ if there is some hyperplane $H=[\psi=\alpha]$ such that $\xi\in H,P\not\subseteq H$ and $P$ lies in one of the half space determined by $H,$ namely
> $$\psi(\xi)=\alpha,\psi\big{|}_P\geq \alpha~\text{and}~\exists x_0\in P,\psi(x_0)>\alpha$$
> here $0\ne\psi\in X^{\prime}$ (the algebraic dual space of $X$). And such a hyperplane is said to support $P$ at $\xi.$

Now let $X=\ell^{p}$ with $1\leq p<+\infty, P\subseteq X$ is the positive wedge defined by
$$P=\left\{x=(x_n)\in X:x_n\geq 0\right\}$$
let $\xi=(\xi_n)\in P$ be a point with positive coordinates, namely $\xi_n> 0.$ I want to show that $\xi$ is not a support point of $P.$

Here is my work:

Suppose by contradiction that there is some hyperplane $H=[\psi=\alpha]$ that supports $P$ at $\xi.$ If $\alpha>0,$ note that $\frac{\xi}{2}\in P,$ so we have $\alpha\leq \psi(\frac{\xi}{2})=\frac{1}{2}\psi(\xi)=\frac{1}{2}\alpha,$ which is absurd! Thus $\alpha\leq 0,$ similarly we can get $\alpha\geq 0$ and consequently $\alpha=0.$

If $\psi$ is a bounded linear functional, by Riesz's representation there is some $\eta=(\eta_n)\in \ell^{q}$ ($1/p+1/q=1$) such that $\psi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n\eta_n$ for all $x=(x_n)\in X.$ Since $e_n=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)\in P$ ($1$ is in the n-th component) and $\psi\big{|}_P\geq 0,$ we have $\eta_n=\psi(e_n)\geq 0,\forall n.$ So $0=\psi(\xi)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\xi_n\eta_n\geq 0,$ the equality sign holds iff $\eta_n=0,\forall n$ since $\xi_n>0,$ we derive that $\eta_n=0,\Rightarrow \psi=0,$ which is a contradiction!

Hence it remains to consider the case when $\alpha=0$ and $\psi$ is a unbounded linear functional.

I also make some efforts in this case but it seems to be of less help: Because $P\not\subseteq H,$ we can find some $y=(y_n)\in P$ such that $\psi(y)>0,$ if we can find some $\lambda>0$ so that $\xi-\lambda y\in P,$ then by linearity we have $0\leq \psi(\xi-\lambda y)=-\lambda\psi(y)<0,$ which leads to a contradiction and completes the proof. But the problem is that such a $\lambda$ may not exists (for example if $\xi_n/y_n\to 0,y_n>0$ and such a $\lambda$ exists, then $\xi-\lambda y\in P$ implies $\xi_n-\lambda y_n\geq 0$ or equivalently $\xi_n/y_n\geq \lambda,$ let $n\to\infty$ we can see $\lambda=0$.).

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Are you sure that the functional defining the hyperplane is allowed to be unbounded?

Comment: Yes. In fact, this is an example given by Richard in his Geometric Functional Analysis and its Applications in page 21, chapter 1 (he does not explain for it anyway). In this chapter he only discusses the general vector space (not even with a norm or topology) and then he defines a hyperplane to be the level set of some linear functional, so in this question I think it's necessary to include the case when the linear functional is unbounded. @PhoemueX

Comment: @Tiffany: I assume you mean the book by Holmes? (Richard is seems to be his first name.)

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Oh yes! It's my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functional $\psi$ is positive (since $\alpha = 0$) and positive functionals on $\ell^p$ (and more generally on Banach lattices) are automatically continuous. See for instance Theorem II.5.3 on page 84 of Helmut H. Schaefer's book "Banach Lattices and Positive Operators", 1974 ([zbMATH link](https://zbmath.org/0296.47023)).

(One might remark, by the way, the Holmes' definition of support points is really very algebraic, probably due to the fact that the book seems to be set mainly a vector space setting. When working on Banach spaces one would typically prefer to define support points by means of bounded linear functionals.)

Comment: I figure it out, many thanks!

Comment: Do you know how the answer will change if $\ell^p$ is replaced here by $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis: The automatic continuity of positive functionals is also true on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$; see for instance Theorem 2.32 and Corollary 2.34 on pages 83-84 of the book "Aliprantis and Tourky: Cones and Duality (2007)". As the continuous dual of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is $c_{00}$, the same characterization of non-support points as in the $\ell^p$-case (for $1 \le p < \infty$) holds (by essentially the same proof as in the question).

Comment: @JochenGlueck : Thank you for your response and the further reference.